# Given a CLPlacemark is it possible to get an image of that location?

Tags: ios6, mapkit, cllocation

I want to do something similar to what Apple Maps does - when you select the annotation for a pin, the detail view includes an picture of the place.  I cannot find any information on how we mere mortals can do this.  Is this private API and I'm out of luck, or am I just searching for the wrong keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a mapview that doesn't allow user interaction